# VuetifyJS: how to get rid of the v-stepper component elevation?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-stepper

When using the [`v-stepper`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers) component in Vuetify, there is a default border like shape that appears on the edges:

[image]

I want to remove it. I tried to set the [`elevation`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/elevation) to 0 but it did not work.

```
<v-stepper v-model="e1" class="elevation-{0}">
```

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/begueradj/pen/ReWXRM?editors=1010)

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not `elevation-{0}`, but `elevation-0`.
Elevation [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/elevation):

> You can set an element's elevation by using the class `elevation-{n}`, where `n` is a integer between 0-24 corresponding to the desired elevation.

So actually you need to remove parentheses as well.
Should be clear because you [can't use parentheses in class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors) as far as I know.

Comment: Any thought about why the prop elevation from the component is not working? Also flat not working ...

Comment: @Ignasi Which Vuetify version? Also could you provide chunk of relevant code, just to be sure?

Comment: With <v-stepper
      v-model="currentStep"
      vertical
      non-linear
      elevation="0"
    >  I still got the elevation. 

However, when adding class="elevation-0", the elevation disappears.

Version -> vuetify@2.3.10

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

just put the following

```
<v-stepper v-model="e1" class="elevation-0">
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding some CSS works (at least w/ your pen):

```
.v-stepper__header {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: I had to add the !important tag for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

`<v-stepper v-model="e1" flat>` for removing round edges and

```
.v-stepper__header {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

to remove header shadow